# How to fetch a Pseudo column based on a condition while retrieving data using SELECT query

Tags: oracle

It is Oracle DB. I have a table as mentioned below

```
PRODUCT  SKU
P1      P1S1
P1      P1S2
P1      P1S3
P1      P1S4
P2      P2S1
P2      P2S2
P2      P2S3
P2      P2S4
```

I need an output from the above table using SELECT query as mentioned below

```
PRODUCT  SKU         XYZ
P1      P1S1        P1S2/P1S3/P1S4
P1      P1S2        P1S1/P1S3/P1S4
P1      P1S3        P1S1/P1S2/P1S4
P1      P1S4        P1S1/P1S2/P1S3
P2      P2S1        P2S2/P2S3/P2S4
P2      P2S2        P2S1/P2S3/P2S4
P2      P2S3        P2S1/P2S2/P2S4
P2      P2S4        P2S1/P2S2/P2S3
```

Please assist me on this. Thanks!!

Comment: You may want to try and explain in human language the logic behind the expected output. That'll get you half way towards writing it as a SQL query.

Comment: Are you looking for a / delimited list of the other SKU's for that same product?

Comment: Yes @ Jonathan Fite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never mentioned about database version but tested on Oracle Live Sql 18.4(Sql fiddle is down).By using listagg analytic function which is available in Oracle 11gr2 and above

```
    CREATE TABLE product(id char(2),sku char(4)) NOLOGGING;

    INSERT ALL 
    INTO product VALUES('P1','P1S1') 
    INTO product VALUES('P1','P1S2') 
    INTO product VALUES('P1','P1S3') 
    INTO product VALUES('P1','P1S4') 
    INTO product VALUES('P2','P2S1') 
    INTO product VALUES('P2','P2S2') 
    INTO product VALUES('P2','P2S3') 
    INTO product VALUES('P2','P2S4') 
    SELECT * FROM dual;


     WITH result  -- listagg analytic function concatenates all sku for same id delimited by /
        AS ( 
            SELECT id,LISTAGG(sku,'/') 
              WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY sku) AS xyz 
            FROM product 
            GROUP BY id 
            ) 

            SELECT p.id, 
                   p.sku, 
                   REGEXP_REPLACE(TRIM(BOTH '/' FROM (REPLACE(r.xyz,p.sku))),'//+','/') xyz  -- replace function replaces matching sku from xyz and regexp_replace removes unnecessary '/'
            FROM product p,result r 
            WHERE p.id=r.id;
```

Result of above query

```
ID  SKU      XYZ
P1  P1S1    P1S2/P1S3/P1S4
P1  P1S2    P1S1/P1S3/P1S4
P1  P1S3    P1S1/P1S2/P1S4
P1  P1S4    P1S1/P1S2/P1S3
P2  P2S1    P2S2/P2S3/P2S4
P2  P2S2    P2S1/P2S3/P2S4
P2  P2S3    P2S1/P2S2/P2S4
P2  P2S4    P2S1/P2S2/P2S3
```

Sqlfiddle on 11gR2  [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b715d/5)

Comment: Replace function produces side effect with unnecessary '/' used trim function to remove leading and trailing and regexp_replace to remove extra '/'between strings

Comment: Thanks Sam!!. The code worked. By the way we are using Oracle 12c